# How to convert an string built up of a list of mongo ObjectIds into a python list of just ids

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas, pymongo, objectid

I have a dataframe with a column containing string representation of a list of ObjectIds. i.e:

```py
"[ObjectId('5d28938629fe749c7c12b6e3'), ObjectId('5caf4522a30528e3458b4579')]"
```

And I want to convert it from string literal to a python list of just ids like:

```py
['5d28938629fe749c7c12b6e3', '5caf4522a30528e3458b4579']
```

`json.loads` & `ast.literal_eval` both fails because string contains `ObjectId`

Comment: How do you have that df in the first place?

Comment: Oh right, I should have mentioned it. I fetch data from mongodb version 2.6

Comment: In this case it's easier to supply an example dataframe, read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I share this regex: https://regex101.com/r/m5rW2q/1

You can click on codegenerator for example:

```
import re

regex = r"ObjectId\('(\w+)'\)"

test_str = "[ObjectId('5d28938629fe749c7c12b6e3'), ObjectId('5caf4522a30528e3458b4579')]"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

output:

```
Match 1 was found at 1-37: ObjectId('5d28938629fe749c7c12b6e3')
Group 1 found at 11-35: 5d28938629fe749c7c12b6e3
Match 2 was found at 39-75: ObjectId('5caf4522a30528e3458b4579')
Group 1 found at 49-73: 5caf4522a30528e3458b4579
```

for your example:

```
import re 
regex = r"ObjectId\('(\w+)'\)" 

test_str = "[ObjectId('5d28938629fe749c7c12b6e3'), ObjectId('5caf4522a30528e3458b4579')]" 

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE) 
[i.groups()[0] for i in matches]
```

output:

```
['5d28938629fe749c7c12b6e3', '5caf4522a30528e3458b4579']
```

And all about regex you can find here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: Thanks, `r"ObjectId\('(\w+)'\)"` works & I used `re.findall` instead to avoid loop

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use replace

```
a = "[ObjectId('5d28938629fe749c7c12b6e3'), ObjectId('5caf4522a30528e3458b4579')]"
a.replace('ObjectId(', '').replace(")","")
#Output:
"['5d28938629fe749c7c12b6e3', '5caf4522a30528e3458b4579']"
```

Comment: This is not safe because second replace `.replace(")","")` might malform data because I'm not guaranteed to only have strings with `ObjectId()`

Answer (score 1):

Locate the rows; split at '; select items 1 and 3 from list:

```
my_df.loc[my_df["my_column"].str.contains("ObjectId"),"my_column"].str.split("'")[0][1:4:2]
```

Gives exactly a list of two elements:

```
['5d28938629fe749c7c12b6e3', '5caf4522a30528e3458b4579']
```

Answer (score 0):

Can make use of list comprehension

```
list_of_str = [str(id) for id in list_of_ids]
```

This will give us the expected result.

```
['5d28938629fe749c7c12b6e3', '5caf4522a30528e3458b4579']
```